# Error in console when device does not have internet(data) access

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

when I launch my app normally with 3g/wifi on, I get no error within the console. When I disable data access (aka airplane mode) for testing purposes, I get the following error message when the app launches within the console :

```
 2011-11-16 19:17:40.440 Juice[8674:707] Reachability Flag Status: -- -------   networkStatusForFlags
 2011-11-16 19:17:41.292 Juice[8674:707] Applications are expected to have a root view    controller at the end of application launch
```

May it be noted that I get a uialertview that pops up when the app detects no data connection and that I am using a tab bar controller. I have no idea why I am getting these error messages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you checking for internet? Would you be able to post some code from your App Delegate?

Comment: Randall, has been solved thanks to chown. See below but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Those are not error message per-say, but rather notification messages letting you know that there is no network connection.  To disable them you can open up your local copy of `Reachability.m` and change this:

```
#define kShouldPrintReachabilityFlags 1
```

To:

```
#define kShouldPrintReachabilityFlags 0
```

The line is just below the `#import "Reachability.h"` line.

[Reachability.m source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_6)
[Reachability.h source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Classes_Reachability_h-DontLinkElementID_5)

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply chown, however I cannot find this line of code within my Reachability.h file. So I decided to add #define kShouldPrintReachabilityFlags 0 under #import. No luck, same deal.

Comment: Its in the .m file, Reachability.m

Comment: Thank you chown! It got rid of my reachability issue but do you by any chance know why I am still getting   2011-11-16 19:17:41.292 Juice[8674:707] Applications are expected to have a root view    controller at the end of application launch?

Comment: Thats most likely because your app delegate didFinishLaunching method doesnt add a view controller to self.view before returning.

Comment: so what code should I add within didFinishLaunching? Thanks again

Comment: @marcus13 If you can post the code for your method (in a new question) I can probably tell you what is wrong with it and what needs to be fixed/added/etc.  Just put the link to the new question in a comment here and I can help you with it.  (A seperate question will make it a lot easier for people with this same problem to find a solution in the future.)

Comment: Good point. Thanks for the advice. Here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190567/applications-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-console

Comment: Sorry to be annoying and repetitive with questions but you seem to have a very good understanding of app development. I have one final error in the console and I will be able to submit my app (finally). Here is the link to my question, I have searched it up but no luck with any of the solutions? thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190989/wait-fences-failed-to-receive-reply-10004003-error-still-appearing