# Compling Xcode Project Application Windows are expected to have a root view controller

Tags: xcode

How do i fix this error? iphone simulator works but when I use ipad i get this in console.. 2013-05-25 20:59:17.556 YourRSS[2717:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

```
    //
//  AppDelegate.m
//  YourRSS
//
//  Created by Mohammad Komeili on 5/17/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 MOMEKS. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController_iPad2.h"


@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;

    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    }
  /*  }else{

        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad2" bundle:nil];
        self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    }
    */

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706828/application-windows-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-a

Comment: please help that is different code... Im new to coding and I need to know how to fix. please

Comment: note i have the following xib.

Comment: I think You are compiling an older project in newer iOS. Try creating a new project and copy the classes over and make the necessary connections in xib then compile again. The warning will go away.

Comment: Check that your navigationController is not nil

Answer (score 0):

The part of the code that is commented out was what would have executed if you were not on an iPhone (see: `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`).  Since you're skipping over the creation of the navigation controller when you're on an iPad, it stays `nil`...which gives you the obvious error.

Comment: im getting this problem now when I change

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "this" problem and I don't know what you changed to or from.