# Objective C / IOS5 - Root View - Build From Empty Application Template (XCODE)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, interface

For learnings purposes I am trying to build an "SingleView" application from the ground up.

Almost - I use the "EmptyApp" template. I do that to understand the way a view is instantiated in an iPhone App.

So far I got the following:

- AppDelegate.h
- AppDelegate.m
- StoryBoard (With a ViewController and one nested view. The viewController is also bound to my class ViewController)
- ViewController.h
- ViewController.m

I copied the script from the "SingleViewApp Template" over. But still my view isn't shown when I test the app.

Looks like I am missing something. It must be a binding or something like that, as the script itself should be identically. Also the console is giving me the following message:

> "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end
>   of application launch"

OK. How I tell my app, take my view and use it as root view?

Thanks Guys....
Every help is appreciated

mogio

Comment: possible duplicate of [applications expected to have a root view controller console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190567/applications-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-console)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your project info.plist you will need to specify the main storyboard file

[image]

Comment: OH MY GOD - THANKS OMAR - 50 secs.... ! stack overflow is sick.... you guys here are really stunning!..

Comment: Hey Omar... unfortunately it's still not working. also I tried the other steps mentioned on this page :(

Comment: I still get the message about the root view. Although the ViewController is set to initial. In fact it was already anyway. Also adding the MainStoryBoard entry to the info did not help.

Comment: Okay. My fault! It's working! Seems that my iPhone was loading an old version for some reason. Thanks Again !

Answer (score 1):

in your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOption, you should have something like:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

also check your main.m

```
retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
```

you should set the class name that implements the  UIApplicationDelegate protocol, usually its the AppDelegate

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder < UIApplicationDelegate >

Comment: hmmm... weird that in the SingleView Template this Code isn't mentioned... any idea why?

Comment: maybe because you are using Storyboard, you dont need to define this code when you are using storyboard. try create a new SingleView template, uncheck the use storyboard, and you will find this line of codes.

Comment: Okay one question. When not using the storyboard you would program views and controls by scripting them instead of drawing them. Is that right?

Comment: you can still use Interface Builder even without using StoryBoard, thats the old technique since StoryBoard is added.
Create New File > check "With xib for user interface"

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard you need to set the view controller as "Initial View Controller". It is located in the properties (Attributes Inspector) on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the answer of Omar Abdelhafith :

In addition to adding the Property "Main storyboard file base name" value is your storyboard file name (without the extention .storyboard).

You need to change your AppDelegate like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /*self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];*/
    return YES;
}
```