# need help understanding my error on my first iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, interface-builder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [applications expected to have a root view controller console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190567/applications-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-console)

I'm trying to build the first app by following a book step by step but I guess I'm making a mistake.
it's a simple view app with just a logo nd a label and then I click build and run and it says "build succeded", but when ios simulator pop up the app is still blank, even if I go back home and ropen the app nothing change.
I see on the debug window this statement:

> 2012-10-26 04:07:03.376 welcome[1219:c07] Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

AS far as I understand my app lacks of a root view controller but how can I implement it?

Comment: That means you haven't set your app `rootViewController` ... Show your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method body ....It should look like @NSPostWhenIdle example -

Comment: in fact I can't see my view controller on my didfinishlaunchinfwithoptions: BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

Answer (score 1):

You specify the root view controller in your appDelegate class. It should look something like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"theNameOfMyXib" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

The important lines that you need to add are:

```
self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"theNameOfMyXib" bundle:nil] autorelease];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

And under initWithNibName you put the name of the xib you created your interface in.

**Note:** Only add `autorelease` if your project isn't using ARC.

Comment: Thankyou, my root view controller is this. 
It's a little bit different from yours. 
#import "AppDelegate.h" @implementation AppDelegate - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]; // Override point for customization after application launch. self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]; [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; return YES; }

Comment: I edited my appdelegate adding the lines you recommended but it displays some errors.
here i have the screenshot of those errors:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/716/errorviewcontroller.png/
What ARC is?
sorry for troubling you.

Comment: sorry for the low quality img. You can't read the errors. here I uploaded a better quality one:
<http://imageshack.us/a/img267/6672/errorviewcontroller.png

Comment: Thx. I replaced those 2 file of your with mine but it gives me one error about cannot find the ViewController.h (in fact I don't have it) btw as soon as dropbox is no londer down I'll update the project so maybe you can see the problem.