# ios 6 iPhone window.rootViewController crashes

Tags: ios, uiwindow

My app works fine with iOS 5.1 on both iPad and iPhone. In iOS 6 app works fine on iPad but crashes in iPhone while setting the `window.rootViewController = navigationViewController`. I have set Exception break point which stops execution at this piece of code in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I even tried adding it as `[window addSubView:navigationViewController.view]` but no luck. Has any one faced similar issue.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
     rootViewController = [[SpringboardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SpringboardViewController" bundle:nil];   
     UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Could you post didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method inside code

Comment: This works completely fine with iPhone and iPad ios 5.1 also with ios 6.0 iPad problem is only with iPhone 6.0 .I have pasted the code above.Debugger stops at `self.window.rootViewController = nav ;` without any error log.It just prints **lldb** in the console.

Answer (score 0):

could you write an exception ?

take a look at these questions

[applications expected to have a root view controller console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190567/applications-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-console)

[Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520971/applications-are-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-at-the-end-of-applicati)

Comment: ogres thanks for your reply but my app works fine with 5.1 problem is only with iPhone 6.0 also there is no error which shows up to provide more information about my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies guys i figured out the problem ,problem was with the `application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow` where i was returning `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` instead of `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` since app debugger was struck at **self.window.rootViewController = nav**, i thought problem was with this statement.

Thanks Ravindharan and Ogres.