# Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem,

I am using following code the application work fine.

```
  Support *panoView=[[Support alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    self.view=panoView;
```

Note: panoView is UIView class

Instead of this I am using following code:

```
 Support *panoView=[[Support alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    self.background_image_view=panoView;
```

This produce following error : **Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch** but app not load.

I need to display panoView inside new background_image_view. Any one help me.

Comment: show your code in 
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

Comment: You have to put it in `initWithRootViewController` rather than `init`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8190567/applications-expected-to-have-a-root-view-controller-console

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `[self.window addSubview:]`
use `[self.window setRootViewController:]`

in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you posted comes from the `loadView` method of your view controller. You must assign a value to `self.view` here, otherwise there is nothing to display for the view controller. This is why your first code snippet works and the second doesn't.

Typically you see this error when you don't assign a value to `window.rootViewController` in your app delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, but I think you are seeing this error because your view controller has no view.

Comment: hi, How to dispaly UIView Subclass to UIView?