# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 error still appearing

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have read it has to do with releasing subviews such as `UIAlertView` or things like text responders. Here is my code for where my `UIAlertView` is being called...
If anyone can help, it would be appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {  
    reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus internetStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if (internetStatus == NotReachable) {
        UIAlertView *errorView;

        errorView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Network error", @"Network error") message: NSLocalizedString(@"No internet connection found, this application requires an internet connection to gather the data required.", @"Network error") delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"Close", @"Network error") otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [errorView show];
        [errorView autorelease];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been getting those `wait_fences` messages on almost every run of some of my Apps for months now.  No idea why or how to fix it, but it can be ignored.

Comment: Apple wont reject based on just this?

Comment: Nope.  Not solely because of this message.  I just had 6 Apps approved last week, all had this message displayed in console every time.

Comment: Perfect! just out of curiosity, how long does it usually take for them to accept or reject an app?

Comment: anywhere from a week to a month in my experience.

Comment: They pick up steam in time for the holiday season, then let out nearly all of the air after the holidays.  So if you want an app approved fast (1-2 days in my case) get it out now!

Answer (score 0):

Add [super viewDidAppear:animated] at top.

Also seems like the alert delegate can be set to nil since the user only has the option to dismiss the alert.